# How to get smooth curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf, smooth

So far i have tried, can someone help me to get the boundary as smooth?
Below is the my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\reflectbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=0]

\draw[thick]  plot[smooth, tension=0.3] coordinates {(5,3.5) (4.91,3.57) (4.81,3.62) (4.68,3.73) (4.54,3.85) (4.41,3.97) (4.32,4.08) (4.16,4.22) (4.04,4.44) (3.96,4.63) (3.91,4.80)  (3.89,4.97) (3.86,5.16) (3.86,5.31) (3.86,5.42) (3.87,5.56) (3.91,5.78) (4.00,6.03) (4.08,6.28) (4.21,6.46) (4.36,6.67) (4.55,6.84) (4.76,6.98) (5,7.11) (5.19,7.24) (5.29,7.29) (5.38,7.39) (5.47,7.46) (5.55,7.54) (5.63,7.64) (5.72,7.81) (5.81,7.97) (5.96,8.28) (6.06,8.61) (6.06,8.94)  (6.02,9.27) (5.92,9.52) (5.81,9.76) (5.66,9.98) (5.48,10.13) (5.34,10.26) (5.19,10.38) (4.97,10.47) (4.73,10.55) (4.52,10.58) (4.27,10.56) (4.08,10.55) (3.91,10.54) (3.71,10.48) (3.53,10.38) (3.28,10.23) (3.07,9.98) (2.95,9.94) (2.81,9.77) (2.67,9.62) (2.59,9.45) (2.52,9.33) (2.43,9.19) (2.38,9.04) (2.32,8.90) (2.27,8.73) (2.21,8.57) (2.16,8.36) (2.11,8.26) (2.07,8.11) (2.04,7.96) (2.02,7.77) (2.02,7.59) (1.99,7.32) (1.98,7.13) (2.00,6.89) (2.00,6.71) (2.03,6.52) (2.04,6.34) (2.07,6.20) (2.11,5.98) (2.16,5.81) (2.21,5.65) (2.27,5.48) (2.34,5.31) (2.42,5.11) (2.49,4.90) (2.56,4.75) (2.68,4.55) (2.77,4.40) (2.90,4.21) (3.04,4.03) (3.17,3.86) (3.26,3.76) (3.35,3.65) (3.44,3.58) (3.54,3.47) (3.64,3.40) (3.68,3.36) (3.76,3.32) (3.83,3.25) (3.94,3.19) (4,3.13) (4.04,3.08) (4.14,3.04) (4.21,2.99) (4.32,2.92) (4.39,2.88) (4.47,2.83) (4.55,2.79) (4.62,2.75) (4.72,2.70) (4.81,2.65) (4.93,2.63) (5.02,2.56) (5.16,2.52) (5.26,2.47) (5.34,2.43) (5.42,2.4) (5.49,2.38) (5.42,2.49) (5.37,2.59) (5.31,2.7) (5.23,2.81) (5.16,2.96) (5.11,3.07) (5.06,3.19) (5.05,3.3) (5.02,3.38) (5,3.5)};


\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output of my MWE

[image]

I am trying to make this shape which is colored as blue shown below
[image]

Comment: So you want pgf to approximate curves? Or what exactly do you mean with smooth? Why don't you simply take the shape of a quote (which should be smooth) and draw something over it to make it white?

Comment: I might be wrong, but the problem seems to come from your data. The typical distance between two coordinates is of the order 0.1, but you only specify two digits. It is then not too surprising to see wiggles at the 10% level. It might be worthwhile to try more than two digits.

Comment: I have shown the desired output in the above figure but i don't know how to achive this?@TeXnician

Comment: If you just want to make a smooth curve through specified points, use the Hobby library. But this will show that the problem is the data as @marmot says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=-1]
\draw[thick]    (1.5,7) .. controls + (-0.8, 0.0) and + ( 0.0, 0.8) .. (0,5.5)
                        .. controls + ( 0.0,-1.0) and + (-1.0, 1.0) .. (2.5,0)
                        .. controls + (-0.2, 0.2) and + (-0.1,-0.4) .. (2.4,1)
                        .. controls + (-0.8, 0.8) and + ( 0.0,-0.4) .. (1.6,3)
                        .. controls + ( 0.0, 1.2) and + ( 0.0,-1.2) .. (3,5.5)
                        .. controls + ( 0.0, 0.8) and + ( 0.8, 0.0) .. (1.5,7)
                ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have this nice figure anyway, why don't you use `potrace` to convert it to a vector graphic, and save it as `eps` or `pdf` file? Of course, you can then load it into `inkscape` and convert it to `pstricks` and from there to `tikz`. The last step does not work on my computer, so I present the `pstricks` file.  (Unfortunately, I do also not know how to translate `\curveto` to `tikz`, my naive thought to use `\draw [smooth]` does not produce the desired result.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(518.66668701,870.66668701)
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]
{
\newpath
\moveto(397.3333234,857.34399558)
\curveto(396.22532343,856.74799559)(391.46665688,854.95732897)(386.666657,853.33332901)
\curveto(381.86665712,851.70932905)(376.21599059,849.62666244)(373.99999065,848.66666246)
\curveto(371.81865737,847.72132915)(366.6666575,845.6333292)(362.6666576,844.07199591)
\curveto(352.53332452,840.11866268)(327.51065848,829.02532962)(326.7146585,828.13332964)
\curveto(326.31865851,827.68932965)(319.46665868,824.11066308)(311.33332555,820.09866318)
\curveto(281.59999296,805.43066354)(239.33732735,778.41733088)(219.46666118,761.37999798)
\curveto(210.93332806,754.06266483)(191.33866188,736.67333193)(190.71732857,735.86666528)
\curveto(190.31999524,735.34933196)(185.25199537,729.99999876)(179.35066218,723.86666558)
\curveto(168.66666245,712.76533253)(152.24666286,692.93333302)(144.13332973,681.33333331)
\curveto(131.63853004,663.46666709)(128.90626344,659.3266672)(122.13386361,648.00000081)
\curveto(118.06826371,641.20000098)(113.13639717,632.3760012)(111.06666389,628.20000131)
\curveto(109.01826394,624.06666808)(107.03226399,620.36533484)(106.666664,620.00000151)
\curveto(105.56253069,618.89600154)(93.64173099,593.20000218)(90.5838644,585.33333571)
\curveto(89.02919777,581.33333581)(86.89426449,576.18133594)(85.88693119,574.00000266)
\curveto(82.93906459,567.61200282)(71.89693154,537.46667024)(69.03799827,528.00000381)
\curveto(54.7234653,480.60533833)(49.4469321,443.46667259)(49.39319877,389.7333406)
\curveto(49.3521321,348.4000083)(52.92293201,313.92667583)(60.75879848,280.00001001)
\curveto(66.45626501,255.33334396)(79.35933135,214.23867832)(85.24999787,202.00001196)
\curveto(85.94999785,200.54534533)(87.82133114,196.00001211)(89.36666443,192.00001221)
\curveto(93.94733098,180.14401251)(105.21666404,158.93334637)(113.80626382,146.00001336)
\curveto(150.20132958,91.20001473)(194.05599515,58.72241554)(247.33332715,47.1130825)
\curveto(261.46666013,44.03334924)(300.38932582,44.01828258)(314.13332548,47.0874825)
\curveto(346.666658,54.35214899)(375.42132395,69.57134861)(398.13332338,91.54734806)
\curveto(431.14265589,123.48748059)(447.28665548,158.66667971)(450.4706554,205.60001187)
\curveto(452.1799887,230.80001124)(450.25065541,252.24401071)(444.81732221,268.4000103)
\curveto(439.52665568,284.13334324)(435.02798912,294.09067633)(427.04798932,307.73334265)
\curveto(411.9159897,333.60000867)(387.05999032,359.75067468)(362.6666576,375.46800763)
\curveto(359.33332435,377.61467424)(356.37065776,379.71867419)(355.9999911,380.20000751)
\curveto(355.63465778,380.67467416)(348.39999129,384.77467406)(339.9999915,389.26667395)
\curveto(331.59999171,393.75867383)(322.97865859,398.77867371)(320.93332531,400.36934034)
\curveto(293.73332599,421.51467314)(278.46532637,437.64000607)(265.73332669,458.66667221)
\curveto(252.53332702,480.46667167)(246.06132718,499.46667119)(239.84666067,534.66667031)
\curveto(237.18666074,549.7333366)(237.57332739,590.0013356)(240.51199399,603.73333525)
\curveto(246.52932717,631.86666788)(258.37599354,657.14666725)(276.62665975,680.79999999)
\curveto(289.40665943,697.36266624)(315.73332544,720.85999899)(336.39999159,734.15066532)
\curveto(345.19999137,739.80933185)(346.63332467,741.28133181)(347.29465798,745.33333171)
\curveto(349.45065793,758.53333138)(352.63599118,772.39733104)(355.56665778,781.33333081)
\curveto(360.72799098,797.06666375)(378.99332386,833.03066285)(383.9999904,837.31466275)
\curveto(384.43465706,837.68666274)(386.23199034,840.13332934)(387.93332363,842.66666261)
\curveto(389.62665693,845.18932922)(393.22265684,849.59999577)(395.75865677,852.26666237)
\curveto(400.44932332,857.19999558)(401.12798997,859.38666219)(397.3333234,857.34399558)
}
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If people feel that this forum is not meant to be flooded by tons of coordinates, I'll be happy to remove this post.